# Bundler::GitError when starting up application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler, rack-pow

In my development machine (mac), I'm running

`pow 0.3.2`
`rvm 1.14.5`
`ruby 1.9.2p290` 
`Bundler version 1.0.21`

I recently upgraded rvm to 1.14.5. When I try to start my app in http://myapp.dev, it gives me this error.

```
Bundler::GitError: git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git (at v2.1.4) is not checked out. Please run bundle install
```

delayed_job is installed in the gemset. I don't know whether the error is coming from rvm or pow

Here is the line in `Gemfile` that declares the dependency.

```
gem 'devise', :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git", :ref => "v1.2.rc2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating pow to 0.4.0 and adding this .powrc inside rails project fixed the problem.

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  source ".rvmrc"
fi
```